# Postgres Audit Logging

Tags: postgresql, audit, log

I have activated Postgres audit logging (edb audit) and can see its creating 2 file

e.g.

audit-2023-06-03_000000.csv
audit-2023-06-03_000001.csv

1st file having only one entry with "authentication"

Whereas in other environment its creating only one file.
I have followed same steps for both environment.

What is the reason behind this